# Is it possible for DAG to detect first run on specific date in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG running every 30 minutes.

Say this is the DAG (using dummy operators for simplicity):

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='My_dag',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=30),
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
)
start = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)
to_do = DummyOperator(task_id='to_do_task ', dag=dag)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='end_task ', dag=dag)

start >> to_do >> end
```

Now, Once a day I want to add another Operator to the workflow to be executed only on the **first run of that day**.

Say it's :

```
once = DummyOperator(task_id='once_task ', dag=dag)
start >> once
```

meaning this `once` is to be executed once every 24 hours and the rest should be skipped.

I can't do that with `PythonBranchOperator` as I can not to something like:

```
if execution_date == midnigt
```

because I have no way of knowing when the first execution will take place. It can be 00:01 and it can be 00:17 etc..

Is there a way I can check if this is the first run per execution_date? I sounds like `TimeSensor`  kind of thing but I couldn't find how to do it with the docs. Is it possible to poke the same DAG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the previous execution date (`prev_ds` macro) and compare it with the current execution date (`ds` macro) in a `BranchPythonOperator`. Example:

```
start = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='end_task ', dag=dag)
once = DummyOperator(task_id='once_task', dag=dag)
dummy_task_id_that_does_nothing = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task_id_that_does_nothing', dag=dag)

def check_if_task_already_ran(**context):
    ds = context.get('ds')
    prev_ds = context.get('prev_ds')

    print(context)
    print(ds)
    print(prev_ds)

    if prev_ds == ds:
        return 'dummy_task_id_that_does_nothing' #task_id
    else:
        return 'once_task'    # Task that would just be executed once in a day


compare_ds = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='compare_ds',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=check_if_task_already_ran,
    dag=dag)


start >> compare_ds
compare_ds >> once >> end
compare_ds >> dummy_task_id_that_does_nothing >> end
```

Comment: When ever there will be a case where prev_ds == ds ?

Comment: So, if your DAG is running for the 2nd time today the prev_ds will be equal to ds. `ds` is just date

Comment: Ok sounds like a nice hack but it means that the once operator will be executed on the 2nd run of the operator and not on the first. I would love to see a feature in Airflow (sort of sensor?) where you can detect which number of run it is per day.. maybe even a simple execution counter that will be rendered/templated

Comment: TypeError: check_if_task_already_ran() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: still not working. return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)  TypeError: check_if_task_already_ran() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next_execution_date'

Comment: Oops sorry I missed `**context` in `check_if_task_already_ran`. Give it another shot :)

Comment: I think the tasks in the branch should be switched

Comment: When I do:       ds = context.get('ds')
    prev_ds = context.get('prev_ds')
    log.info(ds)
    log.info(prev_ds)    the log shows me INFO - 2019-01-17  INFO - None

Comment: Kaxil this doesn't work prev_ds  never equals to ds. I let it run for whole weekend. It always skip.

Comment: @Luis - Have you joined slack for Airflow. Let's talk there and figure out the issue

Comment: Kaxil this happens since prev_ds = context.get('prev_ds') log.info(prev_ds) always gives None (In 1.9)    Maybe this bug was fixed in newer versions?